# Formula to calculate sum by builder and weekday

Tags: formula, spreadsheet, weekday

I need a formula (not a macro) that will do the following:
write formula in such a manner that cells `I7` to `P7` refelct the total amount spent by all the Builders menitioned.

Please calculate weekdays only. The chart begins in cell B2 (pictures)

[image: img of chart]

Comment: You need to add  the column headers.

Comment: They're on there: Long date, date, builder, units, amount

Comment: Have you considered using a pivot table? This would be useful if you need to see a quick summary/total.

Comment: Indeed I tried that, but I lose the weekday in translation and that's part of the need- to eliminate the weekends from the total.

Answer (score 0):

This is the test data i used:

[image: data]

You will need to:

1. Add an extra column at the end and name it "day"
2. Enter the following formula in cell `F2`  (the new column you just created): `=WEEKDAY(B2)`
3. Enter the following formula in `I2`:

`=SUMIFS($E$2:$E$9,$F$2:$F$9,">1",$F$2:$F$9,"<7",$C$2:$C$9,C2)`

and copy it down to the end of your data

4. Copy the names in column C to column H.

This will add up all the work done on weekdays only for each worker. If you want the names on one row and the amounts below them, you can transpose columns H and I.